# How to prove the center of $End_{Ab}(R)$ is isomorphic to the center of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is is an exercise from Chapter $0$:Algebra. It's the whole excercise below:

"Let $R$ be a ring, and let $E=End_{Ab}(R)$ be the ring of endomorphisms of the underlying abelian group $(R,+)$. Prove that the center of $E$ is isomorphic to the center of $R$. (Firstly prove that $\alpha\in E$ commutes with all right-multiplications by elements of $R$, then $\alpha$ is left-multiplication by an element of $R$)."

I proved what's in the brackets. But I don't know what to do next.

We know there is an injective ring homomorphism:
$\qquad$    $\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$    $\lambda:R\rightarrow End_{Ab}(R)$
$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$ $\qquad$$r\mapsto\lambda_{r},$

in which $\lambda_{r}$ is the multiplication by r.

From the content in the brackets, I know the center of $E$ must be contained in the set of left-multiplications. For any endomorphism in the center of $E$, it commutes with every left-multiplication. Denote the centers of $R$ and $E$ by $C(R)$ and $C(E)$ respectively, we can get that $C(E)\subseteq \lambda(C(R))$. Thus I think $C(E)$ supposed to be isomorphic to a proper subring of $C(R)$.

What's wrong with my thinking, and how to solve it correctly?

Ask for help!!! >~<

Comment: This post may help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67805/why-are-the-centers-of-r-and-textend-textabr-isomorphic?rq=1. The same question was asked in there as far as I see.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's my fault not to search carefully==

Comment: You are welcome!